# stopping/killing/discarding the gwt event if it is Event.ONPASTE

Tags: events, gwt

I want to disable  the paste event.for this I caught the paste event. But I'm failing to kill the event. If there is any chance to do it,pls give me the solution.
I tried `event.cancelBubble(true);` and  `event.stopPropagation();` but these two are not working for my requirement.
My code:

```
class MyTextBox extends TextBox {
    public MyTextBox() {
        super();
        sinkEvents(Event.ONPASTE);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
        super.onBrowserEvent(event);

        if(event.getTypeInt() == Event.ONPASTE){
            // Window.alert(":: paste founded::");
             //---- now i want to kill my current event.
        }
    }
}
```

pls show me the way to achieve my requirement. If I'm in wrong track to disable paste event then please provide me the other solution.

thanks in advance

Arun Kumar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
    event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: I already applied it ,but it is not working as the text paste function is taking place.

Answer (score 0):

Do not call `super.onBrowserEvent(event);` if you want to cancel the event.